# Override ANT_HOME property in command line

Tags: java, ant

I am writing a Java RCP application, where I input a file path from user for `ANT_HOME` and then evaluate the version for validation. 
However, when I set `ANT_HOME` property as system property, the evaluation fails because the `ant.bat` script contains

```
rem %~dp0 is expanded pathname of the current script under NT
set DEFAULT_ANT_HOME=%~dp0..

if "%ANT_HOME%"=="" set ANT_HOME=%DEFAULT_ANT_HOME%
```

I do not need to update my `ANT_HOME` but need to override the value so that path entered by the user can be evaluated for a valid/invalid `ant` version for my application.

The issue occurs even when I am using my command line. See below screenshot.

```
C:\Users\tunnikrishnan>echo %ANT_HOME%
E:\tools\apache-ant-1.8.4

C:\Users\tunnikrishnan>E:\tools\apache-ant-1.6.5\bin\ant.bat -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
C:\Users\tunnikrishnan>
```

Can somebody guide me how can I get to workaround on this?

Comment: Why not change your validation to just check for the _existence_ of %ANT_HOME%/bin/ant.bat instead of executing it to obtain version?

Comment: @sudocode I do not need to update my ANT_HOME but need to override the value so that path entered by the user can be evaluated for a valid/invalid Ant version from my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the environment variables of the `ProcessBuilder` instance.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.put("ANT_HOME", getUserAntHome());
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
```

where `getUserAntHome()` gets value from user input.